# Weighting the data by the history

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a input stream 3D data that comes every time frame. Each point is defined by 3D vector of x,y,z. There is a evaluation function [say f(x)] that computes if the point at time t is valid or invalid. Any point that is marked valid is assign a weight using normal distribution.

I am bit confused how to exactly weight this points according to the history window. That is if points remains in the history window for 5 time frame (5 is max) than it must have very high weight while new added points must have a moderate weight value.

My question is how can I define a weighting function to do this weighting for each point that is valid.

At the moment I defined the weighting function as follows which I am not sure if it is correct.

```
exp(-1 + (1/5-t)
```

where 0 <= t <5. But the weights seems not so efficient.

Comment: Your 'weighting function' is not a function, it has no argument and unpaired parentheses. Please check your typing and edit appropriately. Also, can you explain precisely how you use the 'normal distribution' to assign weights? Finally, it seems to me the emphasis you place on increased 'history' is a judgement call based on knowledge of the situation, and I am not sure anyone tell you if your choice is 'correct'. Are there unstated rules for the correctness of such assignments?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about my function, I corrected the typo error. Actually you got a good point however I am also no sure if my intuition is correct. However what I feel is that if a point remains visible in the history window than its weight should increase compared to the points that just arrived into the history window.

Comment: This looks more like a statistics question, perhaps should be migrated to stats.stackexchange (though needs more information about the nature of the data and the problem).